# ! I can't write on file `.aux'

Tags: errors

I'm having the following error message:

```
pdflatex: Not writing to ../chap1_langFormels/chap1_langFormels.aux (openout_any = p).

! I can't write on file `../chap1_langFormels/chap1_langFormels.aux'.
\@include ...\immediate \openout \@partaux #1.aux 
                                                  \immediate \write \@partau...
l.45 ...de{../chap1_langFormels/chap1_langFormels}
```

Project tree:

Main file to run first is principal/techniquesCompilation.tex

```
./chap1_langFormels:
chap1_langFormels.tex  x.log

./chap2_langRegulier:
chap2_langRegulier.tex

./chap3_langAlgebriques:
chap3_langAlgebriques.tex

./chap4_langRecEnumerables:
chap4_langRecEnumerables.tex

./principal:
structure.tex              techniquesCompilation.bcf  techniquesCompilation.log  techniquesCompilation.run.xml  x.tex
techniquesCompilation.aux  techniquesCompilation.idx  techniquesCompilation.pdf  techniquesCompilation.tex
```

Latex version

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
```

%%%%%%%%%%%% Edited after Ulrike Fischer comment

1. If I change **include** by **input**
2. tried also to move **chapters** into **principal** folder as shows folder tree below:

   ls -R
   .:
   chap1_langFormels   chap3_langAlgebriques     structure.tex              techniquesCompilation.bcf  techniquesCompilation.log  techniquesCompilation.tex
   chap2_langRegulier  chap4_langRecEnumerables  techniquesCompilation.aux  techniquesCompilation.idx  techniquesCompilation.pdf  x.tex

   ./chap1_langFormels:
   chap1_langFormels.aux  chap1_langFormels.tex  x.log

   ./chap2_langRegulier:
   chap2_langRegulier.tex

   ./chap3_langAlgebriques:
   chap3_langAlgebriques.tex

   ./chap4_langRecEnumerables:
   chap4_langRecEnumerables.tex

Whatever the case, getting the following error message:

```
(../chap1_langFormels/chap1_langFormels.tex
Chapitre 1.

! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \chapter{Préambule}
                         %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%...

?
```

If I keep using **include** rather than **input** I am still getting the same error message than above.

Comment: you are trying to write to a parent folder. This is not allowed with this security settings. Move the chapter folders into the principal folder, or don't use \include but only \input.

Comment: I have updated question above. still getting errors.

Comment: well the error message changed, but I have no idea why your code is now trying to input a file without name. Try to minimize your code. Don't compile everything in one go.